# Ubuntu command ln -fs

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, ubuntu, nginx

on a mina-deploy script after install monit the script create a link with the monitored services like nginx etc.

but before finish the install show this error,
someone know what is

### ln -fs

command on shell?

> -----> Setting up Monit...
> -----> Put monit/nginx.erb file to /shared/config/monit/nginx bash: line 82: /shared/config/monit/nginx: Is a directory $ sudo ln -fs  "/shared/config/monit/nginx" "/"
> ----->   FAILED

the rest of the script

```
namespace :monit do

  desc "Install Monit"
  task :install do
    invoke :sudo
    queue %{echo "-----> Installing Monit..."}
    queue "sudo apt-get -y install monit"
  end

  desc "Setup all Monit configuration"
  task :setup do
    invoke :sudo
    if monitored.any?
      queue %{echo "-----> Setting up Monit..."}
      monitored.each do |daemon|
        invoke :"monit:#{daemon}"
      end
      invoke :'monit:syntax'
      invoke :'monit:restart'
    else
      queue %{echo "-----> Skiping monit - nothing is set for monitoring..."}
    end
  end


  task(:nginx) { monit_config "nginx" }
  task(:postgresql) { monit_config "postgresql" }
  task(:redis) { monit_config "redis" }
  task(:memcached) { monit_config "memcached" }
  task(:private_pub) { monit_config "private_pub", "#{private_pub_name}" }

  %w[start stop restart syntax reload].each do |command|
    desc "Run Monit #{command} script"
    task command do
      invoke :sudo
      queue %{echo "-----> Monit #{command}"}
      queue "sudo service monit #{command}"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

man-page for `ln` would be a good start.

```
ln -fs [TARGET] [DIRECTORY]
```

Makes symbolic link between files. `-f` will "force" the link to be updated, if already exists.

Given the wording in your error message, I'm guessing `/shared/config/monit/nginx` doesn't exist, which is why the `ln` command fails.